# How to display view in dojo router?

Tags: javascript, mobile, require, dojo

I created a template in dojo looks like this.

```
<div id="test" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" class="test">
     <h1>TESTER</h1>
</div>
```

and imported some dojo library and follow the code of dojo documentation.

```
require(["dojo/router"], function(router){
  router.register("test/:id", function(evt){
    // Will fire when the hash matches
    // evt.params.id will contain what is passed in :id
  });

  // Startup must be called in order to "activate" the router
  router.startup();
});
```

I'am done in getting the value of ':id' in the url, but there is an error showing in my browser console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isVisible' of undefined
```

This is because there is no template called and triggered for the location hash and the id of my template is not the same ( id='test' and 'test/:id' ) because i need a dynamic url.

Thanks in advance, God Bless.. ^_^

Comment: @Ladineko thank you for the response. I asking for a code or any helpful links that that can help me to use the router of dojo and display dynamic data base on the ':id' (dynamic router) in the url.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of how i do it, very simple

```
require(["dojo/router", "dojo/dom"], function(router, dom){
    //Have a config, matching id/widget
    var pages = {
        "id1": "some/widget1",
        "id2": "some/widget2",
    }
    router.register("test/:id", function(evt){
        //require the widget and place it in some div
        require([pages[evt.params.id], function(Page){
            (new Page()).placeAt(dom.byId('somDiv'));
        });
    });


    router.startup();
});
```